# Deiconify an application does not update its content with Mutter and X11

Tags: gnome, xorg, java, mutter

I have a java graphic application using Swing library. If the application is minimized and the graphic content changes (color or whatever), I should see the modification when restoring the window. However, the window is not updated and is still like the previous state. If I resize the window or move it, it is refreshed.

I run this program on a linux system using GNOME3, X11 1.17.2 and Mutter 3.14.4 as window manager. I know the problem come from the message sent by X11 or from mutter configuration because the program worked on another system working with X11 1.10.4 and Metacity 2.28.0.

How can I configure Mutter to permit it to update applications on deiconify, as well as it does for resizing ? Or have I to configure X11 to send an appropriate message to Mutter ? I do not know how to solve this problem at all...